# Can I save this stem or must I cut it out?

Tags: plant-health, succulents, aloe

One of my stepdaughters decided to use their nails to damage my plant. Can I save it or do I have to cut this out?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The wound will never heal, but I wouldn't remove the leaf completely because it is still used by the plant to do photosynthesis. I'd cut the damaged part out and keep the rest until the leaf becomes old and the plant grows many newer ones.

Of course, if you don't like how it looks you can remove the whole leaf, provided that you still have others.

Comment: What Alina said, plus option three is just leave it alone. Whichever you choose will be fine.